# Any examples of handling receive_data and em-synchrony?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, em-synchrony

Does anyone have any examples of building a custom network client that uses `em-synchrony` and `receive_data` ?

Answer (score 1):

[Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath) is built using EM-Synchrony. The Connection class receives the data with a `receive_data` callback.